# How to get all configured receive endpoints in Masstransit

Tags: masstransit

I connect the receive endpoint at runtime using below code, but it will raise an error if a receive endpoint with the same key was already added.

```cs
var handle = _bus.ConnectReceiveEndpoint($"some-name", x =>
{
    x.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
    x.Consumer<TestConsumer>();

    var rabbitmqConfigurator = (IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator)x;
        
    rabbitmqConfigurator.Bind<QueuedWorkflowItem2>(e =>
    {
        e.RoutingKey = "direct."+"somename";
        e.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
    });
});
```

Is there any method I can use to check if the receive endpoint is already added before above code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officially, no, there isn't a specific way to return details on all of the configured endpoints at runtime. I would be highly suspect of an application that just randomly connected endpoints to the bus in the hope that it wasn't a duplicate. Seems more like an application implementation problem than anything related to MassTransit.

However, as a hack, you could use the bus health check, which returns all endpoints, and check if the name already exists.

```cs
var health = _busControl.CheckHealth();

return health.Endpoints.Any(e => e.Key == 'some-name');
```